# Comparing date time in SQLite

Tags: ios, sqlite, datetime

In my app I need to compare date time, and if they are in the right boundaries - derive it. When I need to compare only dates, I used:

```
@"SELECT * FROM allData WHERE (PURPOSDATETIMEDRECT <= '%@') AND (PURPOSDATETIMEDRECT > '%@')", locDate, yesterday
```

where locDateTime = `@"2014-04-12"` and yesterday = `@"2014-04-11"`. All works fine, but now I need to compare date time in format 2014-04-12 10:00:00. I tried: `@"SELECT * FROM allData WHERE (PURPOSDATETIMEDRECT <= '2014-04-12 14:30:00') AND (PURPOSDATETIMEDRECT > '2014-04-12 10:10:00')"`. 
But this doesn't work. 
How can I compare date and time?

Comment: It causes problem due to time zone, before storing and comparing data, you must set the NStimeZene to local Timezone,

Comment: do you still have some records where date was recorded without times?

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem, I store dates as YYYYMMDD. Thus,  where mydate >= '20090101' and
mydate <= '20050505'

It just plain WORKS all the time. You may only need to write a parser to handle how users might enter their dates so you can convert them to YYYYMMDD.